# Как добавить сторонний компонент в Java приложение?

Tags: java

Я хочу добавить календарь [Link](http://nachocalendar.sourceforge.net/) В скаченном архиве есть jar файл, я знаю, что мне нужно как-то прописать путь в classpath, а как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от среды разработки. Если вы используете Eclipse то можно вот так:

1. Нажимаем на проект правой кнопкой
2. Нажимаем на 'Properties'
3. Выбираем Java Build Path
4. Нажимаем на вкладку 'libraries'
5. Нажимаем на 'Add External Jars'
6. Выбираем jar файл на диске.
7. Готово.